# Как сделать рамку вокруг ImageView? snape метод не помогает

Tags: java, android-studio

Создал xml файл, там нашел решение и кинул

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
```

`<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" /> </shap`

но у меня shape, solid, stroke, все выдает ошибку. Что делаю не так подскажите?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У меня есть в xml ImageView, я с помощью него загружаю картинку. Как мне вокруг картинки сделать рамку любого цвета? Я нашел решение, которое скинул в сообщении, но у меня shape, solid, stroke, не воспринимаются в xml файлы (android studio). И я до сих пор не могу найти решение как сделать рамку вокруг картинки.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы забыли добавить обводку. А чтоб под обводкой было видно ваш ImageView то заливку я сделал прозрачной. Код должен выглядеть так:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"

</shape>
```

Ширину обводки вы можете регулировать изменив число в

```
android:width="3dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF0"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
</LinearLayout>
```